# caching the this selector css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, caching

I am trying to cache the `this` selector but am unable to make it work.

```
$(function () {

   var $this = $(this);
    //some code

     $('.collapse').each(function(index) {
       $this.collapse("toggle");
     });
```

What am I doing wrong above?

```
$(function () {

   var self = $(this);

   $(document).on('click', '.expand-collapse', function(e) {

     $('.collapse').each(function(index) {
       self.collapse("toggle");
     });

     if self.is('.i .icon-white .icon-plus-sign')) {
        self.toggleClass("is-collapsed")
     }
     else {
         self.toggleClass('is-collapsed');
     } 
    });
});
```

I have updated my code above

Comment: What errors do you get? Please post a complete code example.

Comment: did you try var myVar = $(this); and $(myVar).collapse("toggle");

Comment: @MIIB - No need to call `$()` again when you already have a jQuery object. That's like doing `$($(this))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) in the global context as you defined it does not make sense as it refers to the entire document. If you want to cache a reference to an individual object which you are clicking/looping over put your variable in context of an event handler/loop.

In your code, as it stands right now, there does not seem to be any reason to "cache" that reference as you can simply refer to the current object as $(this) and achieve the same result (unless you are actually trying to keep a reference to the entire document).

Additionally your variable name "self" is a javascript word which traditionally refers to the current window object so you are overwriting that reference. I recommend changing that name to _self or some other name.

Comment: self is a property of window, not a JS word, so declaring a local variable doesn't overwrite it.

Comment: self also refers to the window object. You are right declaring local variable will not overwrite it, but declaring it in global scope will..thus potentially resulting in some confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really make sense : if you iterate over elements, you don't want to call the function on only one unique element.

You have nothing cachable here.